# infinity sending requst in POSTMAN Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, server

So i would like to register user at the server and to add info to db, but postman return infinity request. And i don't know how to fix it. When running at browser localhost:5000 it shows me message "Cannot GET /" so i don't know what is it related to

here is my server

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const authRouter = require("./routes/auth.routes");
const config = require("config");

const app = express();
const PORT = config.get("serverPort");

app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api/auth", authRouter);

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(config.get("dbUrl"), {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
    });
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server run on ${PORT}`);
    });
  } catch (e) {}
};



start();


///here is my route 
const { Router } = require("express");
const User = require("../models/User");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const { check, validationResult } = require("express-validator");
const router = new Router();

router.post(
  "/reg",
  [
    check("email", "Uncorrect email").isEmail,
    check("password", "Try one more time").isLength({ min: 3, max: 12 }),
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    // console.log(req.body);
    try {
      const errors = validationResult(req);
      if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "Uncorrect request", errors });
      }

      const { email, password } = req.body;

      const candidate = await User.findOne({ email });
      if (candidate) {
        return res 
          .status(400)
          .json({ message: `User with ${email} already exist` });
      }

      const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 15);
      const user = new User({ email, password: hashPassword });
      await user.save();
      return res.json({ message: "user was created" });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      res.send({ message: "Warning" });
    }
  }
);

module.exports = router;
```

port = 5000
[here photo how i send request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meI1L.png)

Comment: isEmail, is a method, anything happening in the console?

Comment: It's probably blocked in the bcrypt and mongo async functions

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thank u so much, a little mistake almost caused a big depression for me, i haven't seen this mistake for 2 days, thank u so much